# Adobe AIR 20.0 + Workers + iOS

Tags: ios, concurrency, air

I want to implement Workers into a mobile app created with Adobe AIR 20.0. According to Adobe, this iOS concurrency is supported starting with AIR 19. Thing is, even if I simply check if the WorkerDomain is supported by requesting the value of `WorkerDomain.isSupported` in my main app, it returns `false`.

If I skip the test of this and load the Worker SWF with URLRequest + Loader ([which should work with iOS & AIR 20.0](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4033753)), the **Loader's `Event.COMPLETE` event is fired**, but the worker can't be created using the bytes provided by the Loader (`WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(workerBytes)` returns null). I don't know if this is because something in my project configuration causes the `WorkerDomain.isSupported` call to return `false`, or the fact that the **file size of the packaged worker's SWF is different to its size in my project's directory**.

Needless to say that everything works perfectly when testing on a Desktop environment (where the file size of my worker SWF doesn't change..).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I was trying to create a worker using WorkerFactory.getWorkerFromClass (https://github.com/silviopaganini/AS3-Workers-Manager/blob/master/src/cacilds/workers/WorkerFactory.as) and on iOS it was returning null with no errors. I solved it by adding the compiler options -swf-version=31 -optimize=false